# How to add Customized comment in MS Word using OOXML?

Tags: office-js, office-addins, word-addins, office-js-helpers

I am creating a word custom add-in. In that user can able to add custom comments with color, bold, or highlight or set other possible options.  But when I try to use directly `<b>Hello This is comment</b>` and also try with the below option. When the first option is to try it gives me `RichApi.Error GeneralException: GeneralException.` When I try to write this as a comment it prints as it is.

> {\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\deff0\nouicompat{\fonttbl{\f0\fnil\fcharset0
> Microsoft Sans Serif;}{\f1\fswiss\fprq2\fcharset0 Microsoft Sans
> Serif;}{\f2\fnil\fcharset2 Symbol;}}\r\n{\colortbl
> ;\red0\green0\blue255;\red5\green99\blue193;}\r\n{\*\generator
> Riched20 10.0.17763}\viewkind4\uc1 \r\n\pard\f0\fs17\lang1033
> uses the parenthetical citation style, with most versions following
> format:\par\r\n\par\r\n\r\n\pard{\pntext\f2\'B7\tab}{\*\pn\pnlvlblt\pnf2\pnindent0{\pntxtb\'B7}}...
> (Smith, 2005).\par\r\n{\pntext\f2\'B7\tab}Smith (2005) stated
> ...\par\r\n\r\n\pard\par\r\nThe Harvard system can vary, so please
> check your institution's style guide to confirm.
> \par\r\n\par\r\n\r\n\pard\widctlpar
> {\f1\fs16{\field{\*\fldinst{HYPERLINK
> "https://mysitehere"}}{\fldrslt{\ul\cf1\cf2\ul\lang2057
> Click here}}}}\f1\fs16  for more
> information.\f0\fs17\par\r\n}\r\n

My Code:

```
range.insertOoxml(
    '<pkg:package xmlns:pkg="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2006/xmlPackage"><pkg:part pkg:name="/_rels/.rels" pkg:contentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-package.relationships+xml" pkg:padding="512" ><pkg:xmlData ><Relationships xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/relationships" ><Relationship Id="rId1" Type = "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/officeDocument" Target="word/document.xml" /></Relationships></pkg:xmlData ></pkg:part><pkg:part pkg:name="/word/_rels/document.xml.rels" pkg:contentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-package.relationships+xml" pkg:padding="256"><pkg:xmlData><Relationships xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/relationships"><Relationship Id="rId1" Type="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/comments" Target="comments.xml" xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/relationships" /></Relationships></pkg:xmlData></pkg:part><pkg:part pkg:name="/word/document.xml" pkg:contentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document.main+xml"><pkg:xmlData><w:document xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main"><w:body><w:p><w:commentRangeStart w:id="0"/><w:r><w:t>' + selectedText + '</w:t></w:r><w:commentRangeEnd w:id="0"/><w:r><w:commentReference w:id="0"/></w:r></w:p></w:body></w:document></pkg:xmlData></pkg:part><pkg:part xmlns:pkg="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2006/xmlPackage" pkg:name="/word/comments.xml" pkg:contentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.comments+xml"><pkg:xmlData><w:comments xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main"><w:comment xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main" w:id="0"><w:sdtContent><w:p><w:r><w:t>' + commentMessage + '</w:t></w:r></w:p></w:sdtContent></w:comment></w:comments></pkg:xmlData></pkg:part><pkg:part pkg:name="/word/_rels/comments.xml.rels" pkg:contentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-package.relationships+xml"><pkg:xmlData><Relationships xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/relationships"></Relationships></pkg:xmlData></pkg:part></pkg:package>',         
    "Replace"
);
```

If anyone has any idea how about this please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to customize the comments you are inserting using Ooxml, just make sure to use the correct styling format to style the comments.

Change the following part of your Ooxml from this:

```
<w:comment xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main" w:id="0">
  <w:sdtContent>
    <w:p>
      <w:r>
        <w:t>' + commentMessage + '</w:t>
      </w:r>
    </w:p>
  </w:sdtContent>
</w:comment>
```

to this:

```
<w:comment xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main" w:id="0">
  <w:sdtContent>
    <w:p>
      <w:r>
        <w:t xml:space="preserve">This is a </w:t>
      </w:r>
      <w:r>
        <w:rPr>
          <w:b/>
          <w:bCs/>
        </w:rPr>
        <w:t>customized</w:t>
      </w:r>
      <w:r>
        <w:t xml:space="preserve"> comment.</w:t>
      </w:r>
    </w:p>
  </w:sdtContent>
</w:comment>
```

Notice the word "customized" will now be bold in the comment.

If you want to add further formatting, like highlighting, here is another sample:

```
<w:r>
  <w:t xml:space="preserve">This comment is </w:t>
</w:r>
<w:r>
  <w:rPr>
    <w:highlight w:val="yellow"/>
  </w:rPr>
  <w:t>highlighted</w:t>
</w:r>
```

You can learn more about Office Open XML styles [here](http://officeopenxml.com/WPstyles.php).

Comment: Thanks For Reply. @Abid Rahman - MSFT
I have Rich Text from my RestAPI and I have to set it as customized in Comment. Is it possible or not and if it is possible please give me a link or reference. It would be great.

Comment: I don't believe you can directly set the Rich Text as the comment, you would have to parse the styling from the rich text and convert it to office open XML styles (http://officeopenxml.com/WPstyles.php).

Comment: Thanks For Reply. @Abid Rahman - MSFT It helps me but if I have added a comment previously then it replaces with the latest comment. Is there any solution or change in our OOXML?

Comment: Thanks For Reply. If I want to set more than one highlighted comment like 
"This comment is bold(Bold Text) and this is highlighted(Yellow text) also Italic(Italic Text)". Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

It depends a bit which styling you need but the WordAPI 1.4 supports some basic styling (like bold, italic, hyperlink).

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/word/word.commentcontentrange

```
const selection = context.document.getSelection();
const comment = selection.insertComment('hi!');
comment.contentRange.bold = true;
```

Highlight doesn't seem supported.